# Windows powershell AWSCLI exits with prompt 'How do you want to open this file'

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

Unable to execute aws cli commands from powershell terminal. But the same works fine with cmd shell. The problem is when the aws command is called through powershell terminal, windows is prompting with a dialogue box "How do you want to open this file?"
Attached the screenshot showing the results when the aws cli is called using cmd shell & powershell.
I have tried re-installing the AWS CLI but it didn't help.
How to fix this problem?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In powershell run the command "get-command aws". You may find PowerShell is not finding the aws command in the proper location. Perhaps you have a file named aws in the directory from which you're running the command?

Comment: You are right, there is an empty file. After deleting the file it works as expected.